# UML Activity diagram for Tic Tac Toe with Bluetooth on android studio

Tags: android, uml, diagram

I have made this uml activity diagram for my app that i am going to make.  I just want to ask if it is readable and correct at any stage.

It was my first time that i used synchronization bars in uml.

[image]

Comment: No. Does not work, It won't pass the first bar.

Comment: Yeah for the first bar i will fix that. Do you have any other suggestions for the other diagram?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you confuse fork/join with merge.

I do not also understand the the beginning initial-node -> decision -> activity-final, nor the end with fork/join/player1/player2

For the special events like disconnection or application-quit whose can happen at any time it is more pratical to use accept-event-action of course associated with an interruptible-region.

If I well understand the application run on each phone, and they are connected by bluetooth, here a proposal :

[image]

Comment: That is a very good diagram. At the beginning yeah it was my fault and as i look at it more now i got a lot more idea how to fix that. Thank you very much. I will use your diagram for my guidance.

Comment: @ThomasKilian oh yes, of course, stupid error, answer edited

Comment: @K.Hadj warning, I fixed an error signaled by Thomas Kilian

Comment: @bruno yeah i saw it. no worries.  By the way what program did you use for this diagram?

Comment: @K.Hadj I used [BoUML](https://bouml.fr/) of course ^^ (I am its author)

Comment: @ThomasKilian as you can see in the [historic](https://bouml.fr/historic.html) I do not do much for BoUML now, the last big change was to add roles/parts, connectors and composite diagrams in June 2018. I just produced the package for Armbian-Stretch on armhf and arm64 yesterday because requested by a French teacher. Some times ago the request was for an other small machine [raspberry pi debian armhf](https://www.bouml.fr/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=437). Yes it is possible to use BoUML on these *critters*

Comment: @ThomasKilian BTW very long time ago I did benchmarks for the fun, including with [EA](https://bouml.fr/benchmark.html#EA). But these benchmarks only value themselves and nothing more, for me to be too fat and too slow make a tool unusable but of course the reverse is false and it is not enough to use few memory and CPU to be a 'good' tool

Comment: @ThomasKilian yes I am the only developer and I am proud to made it alone (if you want to know all its name means 'Bruno Only Uml', because I refused the help from an other guy while searching to name it and used that one as a joke). The font can be changed to a larger one (global menu _miscellaneous_ and it will be saved in the project to not have to do all the times). I certainly do not pretend BoUML is *the* tool and no tool can pretend that, we have all our own taste, and for one usage a tool can be good but not for an other one etc, this is why having the choice is good and necessary.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  I used a little EA with temporary versions (last time to look at roles/parts, connectors and composite diagrams), its behavior is *strange* for me but I am sure BoUML seems *strange* too for lot of people ^^  EA is for sure a very serious tool